# using salty- / cypress-testrail-reporter

Tags: cypress, testrail

I am trying to make use of cypress-testrail-reporter but this does not seem to trigger at all. I have the cypress.json set up as such:

```
 "reporter": "cypress-testrail-reporter",
  "reporterOptions": {
    "domain": "mrgreentest.testrail.io",
    "username": "email",
    "password": "pass",
    "projectId": 1,
    "suiteId": 1,
    "createTestRun": "true"
  }
```

I have also verified the projectID and suiteID. Yet when I run my cypress test I never see anything appear in testrail. Has someone been able to work with this or maybe guide me to what needs to be done or where I can see the results in testrail?

Answer (score 1):

Your config looks correct - the only other thing I had to do to get it working was to enable API access from within Testrail itself.

Open Testrail, go to `Administration` => `Site Settings` => `API` and check the `Enable API` checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

> How did you run your tests?

Integration with TestRail works for me when I run them from CLI, not from Cypress Test Runner.